# Can you dye a Snow Golem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know it is possible to [change the color of sheep using dye](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dyeing).  I've also learned that you can change the color of a tamed wolf this wasy too.

Does this also work on other mobs, specifically the Snowman?

Comment: How hard would this be to test?

Comment: Just to be clear, you cannot dye the actual wolves; the dog remains white, but the collar around their neck changes color.

Comment: @Retrosaur I did test it and it didn't work but perhaps I was doing something wrong.  If something doesn't work it does not mean it is not possible some other way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Minecraft wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dyeing#Dyeing_wool_and_mobs) on dyes and such, **you can currently only dye wolves' collars and sheep**.

Taken directly from the wiki:

> Dyes can be used on sheep by right-clicking sheep with a dye. After shearing a colored sheep, they will drop the corresponding color of the wool, as well keep the color of their wool when it regenerates. Additionally, there are naturally occurring gray, light gray, black, brown and pink sheep that drop corresponding color wool. Breeding colored sheep will result the baby sheep's color to be one of the parental sheep's color, or a resulting color of the combination of both parental sheep's color. The unlimited reproduction of colored sheep make dyeing and shearing sheep a far more efficient method to obtain dyed wool than just dyeing a wool directly.
>
> Dye can also be used on tamed wolves, except on the Xbox 360 Edition. Right-clicking a tamed wolf with a dye will change the wolf's collar (red by default) to the color of the dye. This can be helpful when players are organizing multiple tamed wolves.

Who knows what they may add in the future though. Pink horses?

Comment: Nowhere on that page does it say wolves and sheep are the **ONLY** ones.  In fact the first line says `change the color of wool, leather armor, hardened clay, and mobs` which could mean sheep and wolves but might include more.  It also only mentions sheep and wolves in the changelog, but it never states "sheep can be dyed" it jumps right to sheep regrowing wool, meaning it's possible another mob was overlooked.

Comment: @Batophobia Actually, it mentions wolves and sheep explicitly in the text as per my just added quote. It makes no mention of any other mobs on the page.

Comment: You might at least have a trial instead of just assuming.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I didn't just assume. I knew the answer. I've been playing Minecraft for long enough to have tried to dye a wide variety of things.

Comment: @shanodin Just because those are the only mobs mentioned on the page does not mean those are the only ones that exist.  This answer essentially links to the wiki included in the question and only mentioning things already included in the question.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't dye a snow golem different colors. Here is a video to prove it:

Because you can't dye the snow blocks or the actual snow golem like I have demonstrated, the idea of a different coloration other than white is impossible,

Comment: That... logic makes no sense. You don't dye the bones you feed to tame the wolf, either...

Comment: You can only change the color of the collar, not the actual creature.